# highlighting the backgrounds using php

Tags: php, html

i have this div for my menu bar, here what i want is:

```
<div class="menu_nav" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 0px; padding:0px; font-family:verdana; font-size:16px;width: 100%; background-color: rgb(37,198,255);">
        <ul>
          <li> 
            <div class="menu1a">
              <a class="menu3a" href="<?=$HOME_DIR?>/index.php">
                 <span class="menu2a">Home</span>
              </a>
            </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="menu1">
          <a class="menu3" href="<?=$PUBLIC_DIR?>/about.php">
             <span class="menu2">About</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="menu1">
          <a class="menu3" href="<?=$PUBLIC_DIR?>/myaccount.php">
             <span class="menu2">MyAccount</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>         



          <li style="color:black;font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;float:right;padding-top:5px;">
               <?php
               if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']!="")
                  {
                     echo "<div style='float:left;'>Hello, ".$_SESSION['name']."</div>  <div id='logout' style='float:left;margin-left:20px;' > 
                     Log Out</div>";
                   } 
               ?>
           </li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
```

i want to change the classes of the menu buttons according to the one which we are in the url:

i tried as follows:

```
<?php
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "$url";
if($url=="/signed/public/about.php")
{

}
else if($url="/signed/public/myaccount.php"){

}
else
?>
```

but i dont know how to change the classes of them, i.e., if i'm in the about.php page the about button should be highlighted i.e., that button should get the classes menu1a, menu2a, menu3a to them similarly when i'm in myaccount.php this button should get those classes. else the home button should be highlighted...

please guide me in writing the php code for this asap...thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create the CSS for the selected item:

```
.selected{background:orange;}
```

Then create a simple PHP function to do your highlighting:

```
function currentNav($url){
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==$url){
  return 'selected';
 }
}
```

Place that function in each `<li>`:

```
  <li>
    <div class="menu1">
      <a class="menu3" href="<?=$PUBLIC_DIR?>/myaccount.php">
         <span class="menu2 <?=currentNav('/signed/public/about.php')?>">MyAccount</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

You can modify it. But you get the point.

---

**Update**: To use your existing way of doing things...

First create an array of your urls:

```
 <?php
 $urls=array(
   'home'    => '/signed/public/index.php',
   'about'   => '/signed/public/about.php',
   'account' => '/signed/public/myaccount.php'
 );
```

Then create your current nav function:

```
<?php
function cn($url){
 global $urls;
  return ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==$urls[$url])?'a':'';
}
?>
```

And on each list:

```
  <li>
    <div class="menu1<?=cn('about')?>">
      <a class="menu3<?=cn('about')?>" href="<?=$PUBLIC_DIR?>/myaccount.php">
         <span class="menu2<?=cn('about')?>">MyAccount</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

So your whole list would be:

```
    <ul>
      <li> 
        <div class="menu1<?=cn('home')?>">
          <a class="menu3<?=cn('home')?>" href="<?=$HOME_DIR?>/index.php">
             <span class="menu2<?=cn('home')?>">Home</span>
          </a>
        </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menu1<?=cn('about')?>">
      <a class="menu3<?=cn('about')?>" href="<?=$PUBLIC_DIR?>/about.php">
         <span class="menu2<?=cn('about')?>">About</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menu1<?=cn('account')?>">
      <a class="menu3<?=cn('account')?>" href="<?=$PUBLIC_DIR?>/myaccount.php">
         <span class="menu2<?=cn('account')?>">MyAccount</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: yes, i got the idea, but how can i give three classes to the single element??
actually if u see my code the home button contains three classes, i want to apply those three classes to the about button as well as myaccount button if they are in that url, so how to add three classes as u showed in the function??

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible? Perhaps you could clarify a bit.

Comment: Which are the classes for selected elements? Are they the ones followed by an "a", e.g. "menu1a"?

Comment: yes, menu1a,menu2a & menu3a should be the classes i want to apply for the elements those are selected

Comment: i think u got what i'm asking....ok let me tell u in some easy manner, from the above code u can see that my home button is having the classes as menu1a,menu2a,menu3a which is selected one, now the buttons about and myaccount are having classes as menu1,menu2,menu3 now what i want is to change these classes to menu1a,menu2a,menu3a when the the url is as that one..so from my php code how can i change the classes ??

Comment: yes , i understood thanks can u please tell me why should we include this in the div $url['about'] else can we leave that as $url[''] like this??

Comment: see the new code, I modified it and removed the `$url['about']`

Comment: thank u very much for the code but don't know why this is not working for me....:(
<script type="text/javascript">
$url=array(
   'home'  => '/signup/index.php',
   'about' => '/signup/public/about.php',
   'myaccount'=> '/signup/public/myaccount.php'
 );
function cn($url){
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==$url){
  return 'a';
 }
}
</script> is this the correct way to write the script??

Comment: no, my `cn` function is a php function not javascript, so you'd have to put it in a `<?php` block. See update 3 above.

Comment: yes, i updated like this dude....but don't know why the selected things are not displaying in the menu items....:(

Comment: Put the whole current code you have on codepad.org and give me the url

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all the pages that you website contains. For ex:

```
$all_urls = array('home.php', 'about.php', 'contact.php');
```

Then using your `$url` variable, you can use `in_array()` function to check if `$url` exists in the `$all_urls` array.

```
  <div <?php if(in_array($url, $all_urls)) { echo 'class="menu1a"'; } else {echo 'class="menu1"'; } ?>>
              <a <?php if(in_array($url, $all_urls)) { echo 'class="menu3a"'; } else {echo 'class="menu3"'; } ?> href="<?=$HOME_DIR?>/index.php">
                 <span <?php if(in_array($url, $all_urls)) { echo 'class="menu2a"'; } else {echo 'class="menu2"'; } ?>>Home</span>
              </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do stuff like this is using a template engine like PHP TAL ([http://phptal.org/](http://phptal.org))

This should get you started, but I do not have a test server at hand so there might still be some errors:

PHP:

```
 class Menu
    { 
      public $name;
      public $isActive;
      public $url;
      __construct($name, $url){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->isActive = $url == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      }
    }

    $template = new PHPTAL('my_template_file.xhtml');
    $template->menuItems = array(
      new Menu('foo', '/foo.html'),
      new Menu('bar', '/bar.html')
    );
    if($user){
      $template->user = $user; 
    }
    echo $template->execute();
```

Template:

```
<div class="menu_nav">
  <ul>
    <tal:block tal:repeat="menu menuItems">
    <li tal:condition="menu/isActive" class="menu active">
      <a tal:content="menu/name" tal:attribute="href menu/url"></a>
    </li>
    <li tal:condition="not: menu/isActive" class="menu">
      <a tal:content="menu/name" tal:attribute="href menu/url"></a>
    </li>
    </tal:block>
    <li tal:condition="exists: user"> Hello, ${user}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```